# Arduino leonardo keyboard emulation fail at boot

Tags: arduino

I'm using this code to use leonardo as keyboard:

```
void setup() {
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_F2);
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);
}
```

But it fails to send keys when the computer is booting.
On windows it works.

Is there a way to set arduino leonardo as a real keyboard?

**Edit 1:**

I try with other machine and it works. I Guess this problem is pointed on this question [Arduino PS/2 Keyboard Emulator Issues](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/arduino-ps-2-keyboard-emulator-issues?rq=1)

**Edit 2:**

It fails on a PowerEdge R720 dell server.

Comment: Might be more of a computer BIOS issue than anything. Check that USB keyboard support is on in the BIOS.

Comment: I guess arduino is "partial spec compliance".

Comment: I think it's far more likely that the PC is resetting all the USB devices at boot, and as such, the leonardo is sitting in the boot-loader timeout while the initial BIOS boot screens are displayed.

Comment: Well if this is the case unpluging and pluging again should work. I'm working on a dell server PowerEdge R720.